# Problem in function's arguments recognition by type

Tags: pattern-matching

```
LineCoexistence2D[l1_?(MatchQ[#, coeff2D[{_, _, _}, {_, _, _}]] &), 
 l2_?(MatchQ[#, coeff2D[{_, _, _}, {_, _, _}]] &)]

LineCoexistence2D[l1_?(MatchQ[#, coord2D[{_, _}, {_, _}]] &), 
 l2_?(MatchQ[#, coord2D[{_, _}, {_, _}]] &)]
```

Hello. Is it possible to make the function to recognize by the type of its argument, what it has to do with them? I tried it by using MatchQ, but it's not working...

Comment: Just define the function with each appropriate argument pattern (so use same fn name, differing arg. patterns), and the function with the matching pattern will be the body used...

Comment: @ciao 's suggestion is of course correct. If you have trouble writing the definitions, I would suggest that you edit your question to include a description of the two use cases that you are trying to cover.

Comment: As @ciao says, you could do something as simple as `LineCoexistence2D[l1_coeff2D, l2_coeff2D] := (* stuff *)` and `LineCoexistence2D[l1_coord2D, l2_coord2D] := (* stuff *)`. If you need stricter checking, you can also write helper functions that test if `coeff2D` and `coord2D` are in a proper format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll provide the following as a simplified example of what I *think* you're trying to accomplish - comment if it's not and I'll gladly delete.

Let's make two simple functions that do two differing things on their arguments (standing in place for your `coord2D` and `coeff2D`):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
b[a1_, a2_] := a1*a2
c[a1_, a2_] := a1 + a2
```

Now, let's define a function with differing dispatch, that is, it will do something different based in the argument "type", one thing if it's `b`, another if it's `c`...

```
d[arg : Verbatim[b][_, _]] := 100*arg
d[arg : Verbatim[c][_, _]] := 100 + arg
```

You can see that `d` is defined for two patterns - `b[_,_]` and `c[_,_]`, with the pattern given a name, `arg` in this case. The `Verbatim` construct is one way to specify you want a part of a pattern to be precisely and literally some thing - `b` or `c` in this case.

Let's try it...

```
d[c[1, 4]]

(* d[5] *)
```

Hmm.. the `c` function did it's thing, but the result is not what you might expect. That's because (in very general terms), *Mathematica* is eager to evaluate things, so when it "sees" the `c[1,4]`, it evaluates that to its result of `5`, replacing it in the call to `d`. Since there is no pattern for `d` with one argument, *that* is returned (`d[5]` unevaluated.)

We need to tell *Mathematica* to leave the argument alone momentarily. One way to do this is...

```
SetAttributes[d, HoldFirst]
```

Now let's try that again...

```
d[c[1, 4]]

(* 105 *)

d[b[1,4]]

(* 400 *)
```

... and we see that the function `d` has indeed behaved differently depending on what precursor function was used in the argument.

There are *many* ways to get the same result (e.g. *Guess who it is*' use of a test on the argument blank, etc. Peruse the documentation, play around - that's a great way to learn.)